# Match strings from two files and append line with matching string from first file to end of line of second file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

So this is a bit tricky and I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure it out.

I have two different files, one is in rackdiag format like so:

```
#file1
rackdiag {
  rack {
    42U;
    description = "1.1.1";
    1: "serverone" [4U];
    5: servertwo [2U];
    7: serverthree\nblah [3U];
  }
  rack {
    42U;
    description = "1.1.2";
    1: servertwoone [4U];
    5: "servertwotwo" [2U];
   }
 }
```

Etc.

And the other is a list of server names like so:

```
#file2
serverone.domain.com
servertwo.domain.com
serverthree.domain.com
```

I'm trying to match strings between the two files and insert the line with the matching string from the first file onto the end of the second file with a couple additions. I want it to end up like this in the second file:

```
serverone.domain.com #1.1.1 1: "serverone" [4U];
servertwo.domain.com #1.1.1 5: servertwo [2U];
servertwoone.domain.com #1.1.2 1: servertwoone [4U];
```

I managed to get this far:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat serverlist.txt | while read line;
do
#grep for matching strings and output entire line when match found to $line2 variable
line2=$(grep -w "$line" row01.txt)
echo "$line "#" $line2" 
done > halp.txt
exit
```

Which outputs this:

```
servertwo.domain.com #5: servertwo.domain.com [2U];
```

But I noticed that it's missing some that should match for some reason.

Like, in the actual file I have this line

```
   33: servername [2U];
```

And this line in the second file:

```
servername.blahhosting.com
```

When I tried running the script the output was only:

```
servername.blahhosting.com #
```

Would anybody be able to help me both getting the 1.1.1/1.1.2 etc. to appear in the output and to figure out why it might be missing some of the lines that match?

Thank you very much!

Edit 1:

```
rackdiag {
   rack {
       42U;
       description = "5.1.1";
       1: servertwoone [4U];
       1: "servertwoone" [4U];
       1: servertwoone\nserveronetwo [4U];
       1: "servertwoone\nserveronetwo" [4U];
       1: servertwo-1\nserverone1 [4U];
       1: "servertwo-2\nserverone2" [4U];
       1: servertwoone-1 [4U];
       1: servertwoone-2 [4U];
       1: servertwoone1 [4U];
       1: servertwoone2 [4U];
       1: servertwoone;
   }
   rack {
       42U;
       description = "5.1.2";
       1: server two one [4U];
       1: servertwoone [4U];
       1: server.two.one [4U];
   }
}
```

If there is no [2U] etc. and it's blank at the end, that means it's [1U]

In the case of names with \n, that means that the server has more than one label on the physical case.
I think thats it

Comment: Àny chance you can get that rack file in JSON format?  This is very close, but `jq` does not like it as it is.  But it would be rather easy to do with `jq`.

Comment: I actually don't know. It doesn't need to end up exactly like "serverone.domain.com #1.1.1 1: "serverone" [4U];" . It just needs the relevant information. "1: is the spot on the server rack | 1.1.1 is the location of the server rack itself | servername is obvious | and [4U] is how many rack spaces it takes up. I can attempt it but it would take some interesting vim commands to format it correctly. Also I might have only put a few examples but there are hundreds of servers in the actual use case.

Comment: The only important part is that the server name stays the same and all the other information needs a # before it to comment it out

Comment: Let me try to get it to format for jq real quick

Comment: Why is `servertwoone.domain.com #1.1.2 1: servertwoone [4U]; ` in the expected output when `servertwoone` doesn't exist in file2? Why isn't `serverthree.domain.com` in the expected output? What is "Edit 1" - different sample input? If so whats the expected output? Are those `\n`s literally 2 char strings or are you trying to show us a newline char? If 2 server names are present in a \n-separated string do they BOTH match file2? Please [edit] your question to show a single concise, testable pair of sample input files that covers all of your requirements and the expected output given that input.

Comment: wrt converting to JSON to run jq on it - don't do that. Whatever it is you're trying to do will be trivial with awk and the resulting script will be clearer and easier to enhance/maintain than a jq script. Put your effort into describing your requirements, not changing the format of your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but here's the right approach and a start towards solving your problem:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if ( $1 == "description" ) {
        desc = $NF
        gsub(/^"|";$/,"",desc)
    }
    else if ( $1 ~ /^[0-9]+:/ ) {
        nmbr = $1
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")

        if ( $NF ~ /\[.*\];$/ ) {
            blob = $NF
            sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,"")
        }
        else {
            blob = "[1U];"
        }
        sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")

        numSrvrs = split($0,srvrs,/\\n/)
        for (srvrNr=1; srvrNr<=numSrvrs; srvrNr++) {
            srvr = srvrs[srvrNr]
            gsub(/^"|"$/,"",srvr)
            srvr2data[srvr] = "#" desc " " nmbr " " $0 " " blob
            printf "TRACE: srvr2data[%s] = <%s>\n", srvr, srvr2data[srvr]
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    srvr = $0
    sub(/\..*/,"",srvr)
    print $0, srvr2data[srvr]
}
```

When run against your first 2 sample input files:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
TRACE: srvr2data[serverone] = <#1.1.1 1: "serverone" [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwo] = <#1.1.1 5: servertwo [2U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[serverthree] = <#1.1.1 7: serverthree\nblah [3U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[blah] = <#1.1.1 7: serverthree\nblah [3U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone] = <#1.1.2 1: servertwoone [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwotwo] = <#1.1.2 5: "servertwotwo" [2U];>
serverone.domain.com #1.1.1 1: "serverone" [4U];
servertwo.domain.com #1.1.1 5: servertwo [2U];
serverthree.domain.com #1.1.1 7: serverthree\nblah [3U];
```

When run using your 3rd input file (`Edit 1` in your question) and no associated "file2" (since you didn't provide one) so all you get is the trace output as the data from the first file is being populated:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file3 /dev/null
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone] = <#5.1.1 1: servertwoone [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone] = <#5.1.1 1: "servertwoone" [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone] = <#5.1.1 1: servertwoone\nserveronetwo [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[serveronetwo] = <#5.1.1 1: servertwoone\nserveronetwo [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone] = <#5.1.1 1: "servertwoone\nserveronetwo" [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[serveronetwo] = <#5.1.1 1: "servertwoone\nserveronetwo" [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwo-1] = <#5.1.1 1: servertwo-1\nserverone1 [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[serverone1] = <#5.1.1 1: servertwo-1\nserverone1 [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwo-2] = <#5.1.1 1: "servertwo-2\nserverone2" [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[serverone2] = <#5.1.1 1: "servertwo-2\nserverone2" [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone-1] = <#5.1.1 1: servertwoone-1 [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone-2] = <#5.1.1 1: servertwoone-2 [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone1] = <#5.1.1 1: servertwoone1 [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone2] = <#5.1.1 1: servertwoone2 [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone;] = <#5.1.1 1: servertwoone; [1U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[server two one] = <#5.1.2 1: server two one [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[servertwoone] = <#5.1.2 1: servertwoone [4U];>
TRACE: srvr2data[server.two.one] = <#5.1.2 1: server.two.one [4U];>
```

You didn't tell us what that "[4U]" field **is** so I named it `blob` - obviously change it to whatever it is.

Comment: Hello Ed, thank you for your response. This is basically going to be a script that mixes an nn script which has a list of servers in it in the format servername.domain.com with a rackdiag format script which is used to print a picture of physical server locations in a data center [1.1.1], with their labeled name [servertwoone1]. This is in addition to their location in the rack itself [1:] and how many spaces they take up [[4U]]. The Edit 1 was a list of test cases that was requested by another commenter to give as many variations as possible. The end result should look like:

Comment: servertwoone1.domain.com #5.1.1 1: servertwoone1 [4U];
The need for this format is that the nn script allows us to jump to the server name easily by actively searching and narrowing down the server list when called when typing out the server name in console. We need to # to comment out the last portion of it. The last portion is going to be an addition to easily find the physical location of a server in the data center! :)